# how to call the first line in the text file but it will convert it to porter stemmer?

Tags: python

I am having an error. I am trying to read the first line of my file and wanted to convert it with the porterstemmer

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
with open('notepad.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
word_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
s = word_stemmer.stem(lines) #error
print(s)
```

Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

In additional, the word in the text file is 'eats'. The output I am expecting should be 'eat'

notepad.txt

```
eats
runs
```

Comment: `s = word_stemmer.stem(lines[0])`?

Comment: It would appear that `word_stemmer.stem` expects a `str`, but you gave it a `list`.

Comment: The error is gone but the stem is not working. I have a word 'eats' in the text file, and it is showing the same word. It should be 'eat'

Comment: How can I do it? @0x5453 I added an expected output in the details.

Comment: `f.readline()`(singular) will read one line at a time from `f`.

Comment: @accdias how can I relate your answer from my problem?

Comment: `f.readlines()` (plural) will read the entire file and return a list of `f` lines in `lines` and `word_stemmer.stem()` expects a string, not a list, as argument. Also, you stated that you are "_trying to read the first line..._" of a file.

Comment: Ah yes. But, how can I solve the problem of my error? I really don't get the solution what should I change to get my expected output

Comment: Update the question and post a sample of the contents of the file. That way we can try to reproduce the problem and maybe propose a solution, I'm under the impression that you need to use `lines[0].strip()` to make it work

Comment: @accdias I already updated the question. That's my sample file.

Comment: Got it. Just tested here and I'm right. You need to use `s = word_stemmer.stem(lines[0].strip())`to make it work. The problem is that `readlines()` and `readline()` as well will not strip the default line termination for the lines they read.

Comment: It worked! May I know why do I need the strip for that one? I am just new to python

Comment: Read the updated comment above. :-)

Comment: Clear explanation! Appreciate it! Also, I tried the readline() only, but the output becomes 'e' and back it to default which is the readlines() and it is perfectly working!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one line, then don't read them all into a list

```
word_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
open('notepad.txt') as f:
    line = next(f).rstrip()
    s = word_stemmer.stem(line)
    print(s)
```

If you wanted to stem all lines

```
word_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
open('notepad.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = word_stemmer.stem(line.rstrip())
        print(s)
```

Comment: Tried this but the stemming is not working

Comment: Okay, well, it solves the error. I didn't actually try it with any particular file, but it really has nothing to do with files because `print(word_stemmer.stem("eats"))`, for example, should give you the same output